# How can i update <source src="data" > in Nuxtjs and Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

How can I update the value of "src" with video files?

in movie.vue

```html
<div class="row">
      <video width="640" controls autoplay>
        <source
          id="youtube"
          ref="youtube"
          src="https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/019/697/original/pointing-grey.mp4"
          type="video/mp4"
        />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="Change">
        Skip Ads
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and in my scripts

```js
 methods: {
    Change() {
      console.log("Skip Ads");
      this.$refs.youtube.src =
        "https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/019/697/original/pointing-grey.mp4";
      console.log(this.$refs.youtube.src);
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [`v-bind`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind), bind the `src` property of `<source>` to a [data property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data) that can be updated by `Change()`. Also apply a [`key`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key) to the `<video>` element to create a new element when the URL changes:

```html
<template>
  <video width="640" :key="url" controls autoplay>
    <source :src="url" />
  </video>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      url: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    Change() {
      this.url = 'https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/019/697/original/pointing-grey.mp4'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/JjbPQvR)

Comment: but this url still not update in display when me click

Comment: @ZHARP Use `<video :key="url">`. See demo link in answer.